# How to send data continuosly from arduino to android app through esp8266

Tags: android, arduino, command, android-wifi, esp8266

I'm trying to send data from arduino to android app through esp8266. For the moment, arduino and android app are connected via the esp8266 using the TCP/IP socket API. However, when trying to send data continuosly from the arduino it's recieved only once by the android app. In fact, the message is well received by the app only when I proceed the AT+CLOSE command to close the socket and end communication. This method enables me to get the data only one time. So, I have tried to try configure the communication another time after closing it ( please check my code)

```
void loop()
{
 if(Serial1.available())
 {
  Serial.println("heeeere");
  int connectionId = Serial1.read()-48;

  while(analogRead(4)>0)
  {
    convertedvalue = String((analogRead(4)*5)/1024); //convert read analog  value before sending it to the android app
    convertedvaluelength = String(convertedvalue.length()); //get the length of the converted value
    content = "Converted value is "; //make the response to be send to the android app
    content += convertedvalue; //make the response to be send to the android app
    sendCIPData(connectionId,content);
    sendData("AT+CIPCLOSE=0\r\n",1000,DEBUG); //close the connection
    delay(10000);
    sendData("AT+CIPSERVER=0\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // turn off server 
    delay(10000);
    sendData("AT+CIPSERVER=1,80\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // turn on server on port 80
    delay(10000);
   }
 }
}
```

Android code :

```
package com.example.youssefguirat.socketseverywhere;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;



class Client extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String dstAddress;
    int dstPort;
    String response = "";
    TextView textResponse;

    Client(String addr, int port,TextView textResponse) {
        dstAddress = addr;
        dstPort = port;
        this.textResponse=textResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        Socket socket = null;

        try {
            socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(
                    1024);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int bytesRead;
            InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            socket.sendUrgentData(16);
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
            }

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

/*    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        textResponse.setText(values[0]);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Server:"+values[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.w("MSG","Updating with msg");
    }*/

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        textResponse.setText(response);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button buttonSend;
    TextView textViewSocket;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
        textViewSocket = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.textViewSocket);

        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Client myClient = new Client("192.168.1.25",80,textViewSocket);
                myClient.execute();

            }
        });


    }

}
```

As you can see, I put a long delay in order to get correct and significant answer from the esp8266 but it didn't work :([busy response when trying to close and configure the server each time I send data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiasG.png)

So, can someone help me with it ! I'm really stuck :(

Comment: Show your apps code too.

Comment: The problem is that the receiver tries to read much more bytes than the sender sends. You should change the sender to write a line and the receiver to read a line. For the sender you only have to add `content+= "\n";` before you call sendCIPData on `content'.

Comment: For the receiver add a BufferedInputStreamReader so you can use the `readLine()` function to read lines.

Comment: Alternatively you can make your own read line funtion on the inputstream by just reading bytes one by one until you read  `'\n'`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers , still trying but one more question : in order to receive the message from android side i should terminate the connection by closing it from the arduino side each time i send data ?

Comment: No. Not if you send lines and try to read lines. See if you can flush() the Arduino output.

Comment: sorry but it seems like the  BufferedInputStreamReader doesn't exist

Comment: On Android side you are reading data until the connection closes. `inputStream.read(buffer)` returns `-1` when the connection closes.

Comment: If it is not called like that then something similar. Just google a bit and you find plenty examples. Sorry that i dont have the name at hand.

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue still exist :( Any other suggestions :((

Comment: I may ask if someone has the same behaviour arduino serial monitor side the screen shot is available above.